# Conversion between simplified Chinese to traditional Chinese via Font swapping in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uifont, chinese-locale

I am working on a project where I need to convert simplified Chinese to Traditional Chinese and vice versa. I can do that by character mapping approach (keeping dictionary of simplified-traditional characters), but I was wondering if it is possible by simple font swapping, it should be possible to have different fonts show different glyph variations for the same unicode character.

This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) speaks about the Han unifications.
Is this possible in iOS to do this conversion via font swapping, if yes can you please tell me which fonts I need to use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your project iOS app or a web application? Native apps I’m not sure how easy to handle different fonts. But take a bold step on creating your own font but directly playing with the .ttf files

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to translate between simplified Chinese and traditional Chinese just be swapping fonts or simple character mapping.

For example, traditional 髮 (hair) and 發 (emit) both become simplified 发. So an automated translation from simplified to traditional needs to consider the context to select the right character.

Other problem is differences in vocabulary between e. g. Taiwan and Mainland China. For example computer is called 计算机 in Mainland while Taiwan uses 電腦 - similar to lorry and truck in British/American English.

iOS ships with both simplified and traditional font. These will display same Unicode charcters slightly different due to different writing styles. For example the grass radical (upper part) in 花 can be written with four strokes (like two plus signs) or three strokes (shared horizontal stroke). A traditional writer will typically prefer the first form while a simplified writer will prefer the second. If you do not specifically specify a traditional or simplified font in iOS, it will chose based on users language settings.

Good news is: there are tools which do automated conversion between simplified and traditional Chinese. As far as I can tell, they work reasonably well. A native speaker should have no problem reading and understanding the result. He or she will likely notice the original of the text due to the reasons above, but it will be still much simpler than reading simplified/traditional text directly.

OS X ships with a tool for such automated translation (in the services menu). You might try this out and verify with some native speaker / testers if this gives acceptable results. Wikipedia has a system in place as well you could check out.

Comment: Can you suggest any API for iOS which can do this translation?

Comment: There is no built in API to do MT (machine translation)   You would need to look to third party APIs like Google or Baidu (if your app will be used inside China forget Google they are totally blocked )

Comment: As uchuugaka points out, there is no API for this build into iOS. But there are quite some third party libraries out there. You might want to check out e. g. https://github.com/BYVoid/OpenCC. It is written in C++ and therefore should be possible to include in iOS app without too much problems.

Comment: As of 2018, there are Objective-C and Swift port of OpenCC.  Check the OpenCC link in Klaus Thul's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Neither approach works actually. The character replacement will sort of work most of the time but words are not the same in Cantonese and Mandarin and Taiwanese and Mandarin (though these two are closer)
Font swapping will get you something equivalent to the first approach or worse. It depends on the font mapping and the encoding used. 
This is in general though not a solution to localization.

Comment: Suggestions? Currently I am focusing for Mainland china?

Comment: The correct approach is to have the content translated and localized. This is true for all human languages. In most cases people who natively read HK or TW traditional chinese can probably understand a fair amount of mainland simplified, but not all of it. Don't rely on that.

Comment: Actually app is for magazine, which contain multiple issue and each issue contain many articles so its not only about localizing the app controls but also article text which originally will be in simplified Chinese. I think its not possible to keep localized file, due to this I am using character mapping. or looking for font swapping... Is font swapping possible at all in this case if we leave accuracy to prove a concept...?

Comment: In a nutshell try it and see. The problem is that the glyphs will not match the same unicode code points or same index in the same font. Many good and expensive CJK fonts will include both. But try it to prove your concept one way or the other. Translation from one form of Chinese to another is pretty cheap.  It's a much better route. People won't buy crappy translations.

Comment: In other words imagine people in the UK responding well to a magazine Google Translate produced from Chinese into English. Likely not super compelling.

Answer (score 0):

You can via localization to support Traditional Chinese.

If your system installed Sogou Input.
So you can select this string, what you want to convert to Traditional Chinese. Note: do not select any ASCII character.

And then click mouse right button and select "Convert Text to Traditional Chinese".